# How to add image in headerText attribute of <p:column>?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

[image]

How to add image in headerText attribute of `<p:column>`?

```
<p:dataTable id="tableId" var="list" value="#{beanRequest.list}" >
    <p:column headerText="Date">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.date}"  />
    </p:column>
    p:column headerText="A">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.a}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="????????image here?????????">
        <h:outputText value="#{list.b}"/>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `<f:facet name="header">` instead to specify non-simple-text content.

```html
<p:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:graphicImage name="weather.png" />
    </f:facet>
    ...
</p:column>
```

Comment: is it possible to use both title and icon together? To have an effect like:   <p:column headerText="Username" icon="fa fa-user">

Comment: @gmode did you find a solution for your question?

Comment: @raho I can't remember, it was 7 years ago

Comment: @gmode too bad ;-)