# Primefaces column vertical-text

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I have a dataTable with 22 columns but I will style 8 of them vertical 
 I am using this dataTable

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="" paginator="true" rows="5" style=".ui-datatable th { writing-mode: tb-lr; }"
                 paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15"  id="carTable" lazy="true">
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":form" oncomplete="PF('carDialog').show()" />
        <p:column headerText="column1" sortBy="" filterBy="">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </p:column>
<p:column headerText="column2" sortBy="" filterBy="">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </p:column>
......
<p:column headerText="column22" sortBy="" filterBy="">
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </p:column>
```

Image :

[image]

how I can make this?

Answer (score 2):

Add css `writing-mode : vertical-lr` (or vertical-rl if you want to try) to your column for recent browser

You may want this for old browser

```
-ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; /* old IE 6 and 7 */
-webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
-ms-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
```

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) for compatibility

You may want to use `styleClass="verticalText"` and put this in your CSS file

```
.verticalText{
   writing-mode : vertical-lr;
  -ms-writing-mode: tb-rl; /* old IE 6 and 7 */
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

And go with `<f:facet name="header">` instead of headerText

```
<p:column>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Title"/>
  </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

Another solution, use image replace the outputText by `<h:graphicImage name="verticalheader.png" />` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159014/how-to-add-image-in-headertext-attribute-of-pcolumn)

Comment: <style type="text/css">
        .ui-datatable th { writing-mode: tb-lr; }
    </style>

Comment: please can you help me

Comment: <style type="text/css"> .ui-datatable th { writing-mode: tb-rl; } </style> but not worked

Comment: style=".ui-datatable th { writing-mode: tb-lr; }" this can't work use style="writing-mode: tb-lr;" or styleClass="existingcssclassname"

Comment: @rachid: learn how to make the right selectors. Learn about css specificity. I tried in the PF showcase via my browser developer tool and it works!

Comment: thanks it's work with this script :                                                       <p:column sortBy="" filterBy="">
            <f:facet name="header">  
              <h:outputText value="test" style="writing-mode: tb-rl;" />  
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="" />
        </p:column>